# How to handle collisions in JS/jQuery only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time making collisions for my game in js, jQuery only. I'd like the character to be able to jump from platforms to platforms. Also, i'd like to have a console.log('hit'); when one of the character touch the other one with a shot. I've been trying for the last 2 days. I'm stuck.

Here is my code :

```js
setInterval(bougerPersonnages, 8); //Vitesse de déplacement.
var touche = {}
var batmanp = document.getElementById('batman');
var jumping = false;
var jumpingChomel = false;
var barpos = $("#batman");
var browserHeight = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
var iHeight = window.innerHeight;




var batmanPosX = $("#batman").offset().left;
var batmanPosY = $("#batman").offset().top;
var batmanWidth = $("#batman").width();
var batmanHeigth = $("#batman").height();

var ballePosX = $('#arrow1').offset().left;
var ballePosY = $('#arrow1').offset().top;
var balleWidth = $('#arrow1').width();
var balleHeight = $('#arrow1').height();


$(document).keydown(function(e) { //Fonctionne
    touche[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) { //Fonctionne
    delete touche[e.keyCode];
});


function bougerPersonnages() {

    for (var direction in touche) {
        if (direction == 37) { //Fonctionne
         batman.className = 'dirGauche';
         $("#batman").css('left','-=5px');
        }

        if (direction == 81) { //Fonctionne
         chomel.className = 'dirGauche';
            $("#chomel").css('left', '-=5'); 
        }
     
        if (direction == 39) { //Fonctionne
         batman.className = 'dirDroite';
            $("#batman").css('left', '+=5');        
        }

        if (direction == 68) { //Fonctionne
         chomel.className = 'dirDroite';
            $("#chomel").css('left', '+=5');        
        }

        if (direction == 38) { //Fonctionne
      if (!jumping) {
       jumping = true;
       $("#batman").animate({ bottom: 300 +"px" }, 300);
       $("#batman").animate({ bottom: 10 + "px" }, 300);
       setTimeout(land, 650);
    }
   }

   if (direction == 90) { //Fonctionne
    if (!jumpingChomel) {
       jumpingChomel = true;
       $("#chomel").animate({ bottom: 300 +"px" }, 300);
       $("#chomel").animate({ bottom: 10 + "px" }, 300);
       setTimeout(landChomel, 650);      
       }
      }


 }

  
}




//Fonctionne
function land() {
    
  jumping = false;

}

function landChomel() {
    
  jumpingChomel = false;

}
//Fonctionne
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { // Déclenche la fonction fire
 
 switch (e.keyCode) {

        case 76:
        console.log('ok');
            fire_batman();
        break;
        case 32:
        console.log('ok');
            fire_chomel();
        break;     
    }

});

function fire_chomel() { //Fonctionne

 var posTop = parseInt($(chomel).offset().top);
    var posLeft = parseInt($(chomel).offset().left);
 var bullets = $('#arrow1');
 var bulletElement = $('<div class="arrow1" style="top: '+ (posTop + 50) +'px; left: '+ posLeft +'px"></div>');

    bullets.append(bulletElement);

    if (chomel.className == 'dirGauche') {
     var options = {left: browserHeight * -15};
    }
    else {
     var options = {left: browserHeight * 15};
    }

 bulletElement.animate(options, 0.5, "linear");
}

function fire_batman() { //Fonctionne

 var posTop = parseInt($(batman).offset().top);
    var posLeft = parseInt($(batman).offset().left);
 var bullets = $('#arrow1');
 var bulletElement = $('<div class="arrow1" style="top: '+ (posTop + 50) +'px; left: '+ posLeft +'px"></div>');

    bullets.append(bulletElement);

    if (batman.className == 'dirGauche') {
     var options = {left: browserHeight * -15};
    }
    else {
     var options = {left: browserHeight * 15};
    }

 bulletElement.animate(options, 0.5, "linear");
 var rect1 = {x: batmanPosX, y: batmanPosY, width: batmanWidth, height: batmanHeigth}
var rect2 = {x: ballePosX, y: ballePosY, width: balleWidth, height: balleHeight}

if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width &&
   rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x &&
   rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height &&
   rect1.height + rect1.y > rect2.y) {
    // collision detected!
    console.log('TOUCHER FDP')
}

// filling in the values =>

if (5 < 30 &&
    55 > 20 &&
    5 < 20 &&
    55 > 10) {
    // collision detected!
}
}
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1429119282-bg.png');
 background-color: #B4381F;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 30%; 
 overflow: hidden;
}


#batman{
 background-image:url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1429119282-batman.png');
 width:90px;
 height:90px;
 display:block;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position:absolute;
}

#chomel{
 background-image:url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1429119282-chomel.png');
 width:90px;
 height:90px;
 display:block;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position:absolute;
}

.dirDroite{
 background-position: -95px 0px;
}

.dirGauche{
 background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#fullbody {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#floor {
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
 background: url("http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1429119282-thefloor.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 126px;
 
}

#base {
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
 margin: auto;
 background: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1429119282-platform5.png');
 background-size: cover;
 width: 600px;
 height: 30px;
}



#perspectiveGauche{
 margin-top : 22vh;
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4vh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautGaucheH{
 margin-left: 13.22vh;
 width: 28.87vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasGaucheH{
 width: 29.1vw;
 margin-left: 13vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveGaucheBasse{
 margin-top : 22vh;
 -webkit-perspective: 0.1vh;
    perspective: 0.1vw;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautGaucheB{
 margin-top: 38vh;
 margin-left: 28vh;
 width: 15vw;
 height: 0.25vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasGaucheB{
 margin-top: 0.6vh;
 width: 15.3vw;
 margin-left: 27.75vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveDroite{
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4wh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 39.6vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: 22vh;
    perspective-origin: 200% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautDroitH{
 margin-left: 125vh;
 width: 28.7vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasDroitH{
 width: 28.9vw;
 margin-left: 124.8vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#rectangleHautDroiteB{
 margin-top: 32vh;
 margin-left: 133vh;
 width: 22vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasDroiteB{
 margin-top: 0.2vh;
 width: 22.18vw;
 margin-left: 132.8vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveMilieu{
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4wh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 39.6vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: 22vh;
    perspective-origin: 130% 0%;
 
}

#rectangleHautMilieu{
 margin-top: 21vh;
 margin-left: 68.95vh;
 width: 34.5vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
    
}

#rectangleBasMilieu{
 margin-top: 0.1vh;
 width: 34.77vw;
 margin-left: 68.7vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

.arrow1 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
 transition-duration: 3s;
 width: 50px;
 height: 11px;
 background: url('http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1429119282-bullet.png') 43px 19px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>LEVEL 1</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>
<body>


<div id="fullbody">

 <div id="perspectiveGauche">
  <div id="rectangleHautGaucheH"></div>
  <div id="rectangleBasGaucheH"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="perspectiveGaucheBasse">
  <div id="rectangleHautGaucheB"></div>
  <div id="rectangleBasGaucheB"></div>
 </div>

  <div id="perspectiveDroite">
   <div id="rectangleHautDroitH"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasDroitH"></div>
   <div id="rectangleHautDroiteB"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasDroiteB"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="perspectiveMilieu">
   <div id="rectangleHautMilieu"></div>
   <div id="rectangleBasMilieu"></div>
  </div>

 
  <div id="base"></div>
  <div id="arrow1"></div>
  <div id="floor"></div>
  <span style="margin-left:50px;" id="result">false</span>

 <div id="batman" name="batman" class="dirGauche" style="left: 1100px; bottom: 580px;"></div>
 <div id="chomel" name="chomel" class="dirGauche" style="left: 900px; bottom: 580px;"></div>

</div>
 
 <script src="scripts/script.js" ></script>
```

Also joining a jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/b6hq4xqr/

Thanks in advance for you replies.
Cheers !

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>LEVEL 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="fullbody">

            <div id="perspectiveGauche">
                <div id="rectangleHautGaucheH"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasGaucheH" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="perspectiveGaucheBasse">
                <div id="rectangleHautGaucheB"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasGaucheB" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="perspectiveDroite">
                <div id="rectangleHautDroitH"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasDroitH" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
                <div id="rectangleHautDroiteB"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasDroiteB" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="perspectiveMilieu">
                <div id="rectangleHautMilieu"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasMilieu" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
            </div>


            <div id="base"></div>
            <div id="arrow1"></div>
            <div id="floor"></div>
            <span style="margin-left:50px;" id="result">false</span>

            <div id="batman" class="dirGauche" style="left: 1100px; bottom: 580px;"></div>
            <div id="chomel" class="dirGauche" style="left: 900px; bottom: 580px;"></div>

        </div>

        <script src="javascript.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

break

```
function bougerPersonnages() {

    for (var direction in touche) {
        if (direction == 37) { //Fonctionne
            batman.className = 'dirGauche';
            $("#batman").css('left', '-=5px');
        } else if (direction == 81) { //Fonctionne
            chomel.className = 'dirGauche';
            $("#chomel").css('left', '-=5');
        } else if (direction == 39) { //Fonctionne
            batman.className = 'dirDroite';
            $("#batman").css('left', '+=5');
        } else if (direction == 68) { //Fonctionne
            chomel.className = 'dirDroite';
            $("#chomel").css('left', '+=5');
        } else if (direction == 38) { //Fonctionne
            if (!jumping) {
                jumping = true;
                $("#batman").animate({bottom: 300 + "px"}, 300);
                $("#batman").animate({bottom: 10 + "px"}, 300);
                setTimeout(land, 650);
            }
        }
        else if (direction == 90) { //Fonctionne
            if (!jumpingChomel) {
                jumpingChomel = true;
                $("#chomel").animate({bottom: 300 + "px"}, 300);
                $("#chomel").animate({bottom: 10 + "px"}, 300);
                setTimeout(landChomel, 650);
            }
        }
    }

    var batmanRect = getRectangle($("#batman"));
    $(".arrow1").each(function () {
        var rect = getRectangle($(this));
        if (intersectingRectangles(batmanRect, rect)) {
            console.log("batman has been shot!");
        }
    });

    $(".collidableRectangle").each(function () {
        var rect = getRectangle($(this));
        if (intersectingRectangles(batmanRect, rect)) {
            console.log("batman has hit a platform!");
        }
    });
}

function fire_chomel() { //Fonctionne

    var posTop = parseInt($(chomel).offset().top);
    var posLeft = parseInt($(chomel).offset().left);
    var bullets = $('#arrow1');
    var bulletElement = $('<div class="arrow1" style="top: ' + (posTop + 50) + 'px; left: ' + posLeft + 'px"></div>');

    bullets.append(bulletElement);

    if (chomel.className == 'dirGauche') {
        var options = {left: browserHeight * -15};
    }
    else {
        var options = {left: browserHeight * 15};
    }

    bulletElement.animate(options, 2000, "linear", function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}


function intersectingRectangles(r1, r2) {
    return !(r2.left > r1.right ||
            r2.right < r1.left ||
            r2.top > r1.bottom ||
            r2.bottom < r1.top);
}

function getRectangle(figure) {
    var rect = {};
    rect.left = figure.offset().left;
    rect.top = figure.offset().top;
    rect.right = rect.left + figure.width();
    rect.bottom = rect.top + figure.height();
    return rect;
}
```

I also removed the

```
.arrow1 {
    transition-duration: 3s;
}
```

Most of the problems you were facing were due to your (ab)use of globals. Every experienced programmer will tell you globals are to be used with caution or even avoided as much as possible. That is with good reason.

This only implements the first fire function, but the other is analogue and you should be able to do it yourself. 
Collisions now log to the console.
I tried to do this with minimal changes to your code. I suggest you look into minimalising your use of globals before continueing.

Answer (score 0):

---

Here is what i've done your code :

```js
setInterval(bougerPersonnages, 8); //Vitesse de déplacement.
var touche = {}
var jumping = false;
var jumpingChomel = false;
var browserHeight = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientHeight);


var batmanPosX = $("#batman").offset().left;
var chomelPosX = $("#chomel").offset().left;



$(document).keydown(function(e) { //Fonctionne
    touche[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function(e) { //Fonctionne
    delete touche[e.keyCode];
});


function bougerPersonnages() {

    for (var direction in touche) {
        if (direction == 37) { //Fonctionne
            batman.className = 'dirGauche';
            $("#batman").css('left', '-=5px');
        } else if (direction == 81) { //Fonctionne
            chomel.className = 'dirGauche';
            $("#chomel").css('left', '-=5');
        } else if (direction == 39) { //Fonctionne
            batman.className = 'dirDroite';
            $("#batman").css('left', '+=5');
        } else if (direction == 68) { //Fonctionne
            chomel.className = 'dirDroite';
            $("#chomel").css('left', '+=5');
        } else if (direction == 38) { //Fonctionne
            if (!jumping) {
                jumping = true;
                $("#batman").animate({bottom: 300 + "px"}, 300);
                $("#batman").animate({bottom: 10 + "px"}, 300);
                setTimeout(land, 650);
            }
        }
        else if (direction == 90) { //Fonctionne
            if (!jumpingChomel) {
                jumpingChomel = true;
                $("#chomel").animate({bottom: 300 + "px"}, 300);
                $("#chomel").animate({bottom: 10 + "px"}, 300);
                setTimeout(landChomel, 650);
            }
        }
    }

    var batmanRect = getRectangle($("#batman"));
    $(".arrow1").each(function () {
        var rect = getRectangle($(this));
        if (intersectingRectangles(batmanRect, rect)) {
            console.log("batman has been shot!");
            $("#batman").animate({left: "+=50px"}, 40);
        }
    });


    var chomelRect = getRectangle($("#chomel"));
    $(".arrow1").each(function () {
        var rect = getRectangle($(this));
        if (intersectingRectangles(chomelRect, rect)) {
            console.log("chomel has been shot!");
            $("#batman").animate({left: "+=50px"}, 40);
        }
    });

    $(".collidableRectangle").each(function () {
        var rect = getRectangle($(this));
        if (intersectingRectangles(batmanRect, rect)) {
            console.log("batman has hit a platform!");
        }
    });
}

function land() {
    
  jumping = false;

}

function landChomel() {
    
  jumpingChomel = false;

}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { // Déclenche la fonction fire
 
 switch (e.keyCode) {

        case 76:
            fire_batman();
        break;
        case 32:
            fire_chomel();
        break;     
    }

});

function fire_chomel() { //Fonctionne

    var posTop = parseInt($(chomel).offset().top);
    var posLeft = parseInt($(chomel).offset().left);
    var bullets = $('#arrow1');
    var bulletElement = $('<div class="arrow1" style="top: ' + (posTop + 50) + 'px; left: ' + posLeft + 'px"></div>');

    bullets.append(bulletElement);

    if (chomel.className == 'dirGauche') {
        var options = {left: browserHeight * -15};
    }
    else {
        var options = {left: browserHeight * 15};
    }

    bulletElement.animate(options, 2000, "linear", function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}

function fire_batman() { //Fonctionne

    var posTop = parseInt($(batman).offset().top);
    var posLeft = parseInt($(batman).offset().left);
    var bullets = $('#arrow1');
    var bulletElement = $('<div class="arrow1" style="top: ' + (posTop + 50) + 'px; left: ' + posLeft + 'px"></div>');

    bullets.append(bulletElement);
 
    if (batman.className == 'dirGauche') {
        var options = {left: browserHeight * -15};
    }
    else {
        var options = {left: browserHeight * 15};
    }

    bulletElement.animate(options, 2000, "linear", function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}


function intersectingRectangles(r1, r2) {
    return !(r2.left > r1.right ||
            r2.right < r1.left ||
            r2.top > r1.bottom ||
            r2.bottom < r1.top);
}

function getRectangle(figure) {
    var rect = {};
    rect.left = figure.offset().left;
    rect.top = figure.offset().top;
    rect.right = rect.left + figure.width();
    rect.bottom = rect.top + figure.height();
    return rect;
}
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 background: url('img/bg.png');
 background-color: #B4381F;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 50% 30%; 
 overflow: hidden;
}


#batman{
 background-image:url(img/batman.png);
 width:90px;
 height:90px;
 display:block;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position:absolute;
}

#chomel{
 background-image:url(img/chomel.png);
 width:90px;
 height:90px;
 display:block;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position:absolute;
}

.dirDroite{
 background-position: -95px 0px;
}

.dirGauche{
 background-position: 0px 0px;
}

#fullbody {
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#floor {
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
 background: url("img/thefloor.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 height: 126px;
 
}

#base {
 position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 200;
 margin: auto;
 background: url('img/platform5.png');
 background-size: cover;
 width: 600px;
 height: 30px;
}



#perspectiveGauche{
 margin-top : 22vh;
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4vh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautGaucheH{
 margin-left: 13.22vh;
 width: 28.87vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasGaucheH{
 width: 29.1vw;
 margin-left: 13vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveGaucheBasse{
 margin-top : 22vh;
 -webkit-perspective: 0.1vh;
    perspective: 0.1vw;
    position: absolute;
    width: 45vw;
    perspective-origin: 50% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautGaucheB{
 margin-top: 38vh;
 margin-left: 28vh;
 width: 15vw;
 height: 0.25vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasGaucheB{
 margin-top: 0.6vh;
 width: 15.3vw;
 margin-left: 27.75vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveDroite{
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4wh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 39.6vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: 22vh;
    perspective-origin: 200% 0%;
}

#rectangleHautDroitH{
 margin-left: 125vh;
 width: 28.7vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasDroitH{
 width: 28.9vw;
 margin-left: 124.8vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#rectangleHautDroiteB{
 margin-top: 32vh;
 margin-left: 133vh;
 width: 22vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
}

#rectangleBasDroiteB{
 margin-top: 0.2vh;
 width: 22.18vw;
 margin-left: 132.8vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

#perspectiveMilieu{
 -webkit-perspective: 4vh;
    perspective: 4wh;
    position: absolute;
    width: 39.6vw;
    height: 2vh;
    margin-top: 22vh;
    perspective-origin: 130% 0%;
 
}

#rectangleHautMilieu{
 margin-top: 21vh;
 margin-left: 68.95vh;
 width: 34.5vw;
 height: 2vh;
 background-color: #854305;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(2deg);
    transform: rotateX(2deg);
    
}

#rectangleBasMilieu{
 margin-top: 0.1vh;
 width: 34.77vw;
 margin-left: 68.7vh;
 height: 3vh;
 background-color: #663303; 
}

.arrow1 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 3;
 width: 50px;
 height: 11px;
 background: url('img/bullet.png') 43px 19px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>LEVEL 1</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>


        <div id="fullbody">

            <div id="perspectiveGauche">
                <div id="rectangleHautGaucheH"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasGaucheH" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="perspectiveGaucheBasse">
                <div id="rectangleHautGaucheB"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasGaucheB" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="perspectiveDroite">
                <div id="rectangleHautDroitH"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasDroitH" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
                <div id="rectangleHautDroiteB"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasDroiteB" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="perspectiveMilieu">
                <div id="rectangleHautMilieu"></div>
                <div id="rectangleBasMilieu" class="collidableRectangle"></div>
            </div>


            <div id="base"></div>
            <div id="arrow1"></div>
            <div id="floor"></div>
            <span style="margin-left:50px;" id="result">false</span>

            <div id="batman" class="dirGauche" style="left: 1100px; bottom: 580px;"></div>
            <div id="chomel" class="dirGauche" style="left: 900px; bottom: 580px;"></div>

        </div>

        <script src="scripts/script.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

@Soronbe as you can see, i have perfect console.logs tho when batman get shot, i'd like him to be pushed back by 50px from is position (i can do it myself), but when he is pushed, and i want to move it, he gets "freezed" a while before he can move again. Any ideas on how to fix it ?

**EDIT : i just had to lower the animation time. Now i'm struggling with making the same thing with Batman. When i try to do it, when on get shot, they both move. I also updated the script.**

Thanks mate !

Comment: you're moving batman regardless of who gets shot. It also counts as shot if they touch their own bullets (and they do when leaving the character, so just after they were shot)

Comment: @Soronbe i've fixed it, now my characters shoot each others. Do you have any idea now to make the stay on a platform when they hit them ? This is the last thing i need to implement :)

Comment: Your approach has the disadvantage of not being able to see which direction the player came from. You'll have a rough time getting such thing bug free. To do this you're probably better of storing a speed vector for each player, and adjusting it as desired when hit by a bullet, being affected by gravity, hitting a platform or jumping.

Comment: @Soronbe I made the bullets totally work, check my latest answer. My last problem is the platforms... If could help me with that it would be awesome ! Thanks mate for your time and precious help !

Comment: Yea, that was what I was talking about.